# Typescript issue - When using RouteParams I get a type compiler error when trying to get routeParams .id

Tags: typescript

I'm using Typescript with Angular 2

Issue I'm getting is a typescript compiler error.
The actual code works.

**Here is my code:**

```
constructor(_router: Router, _params:RouteParams){       
  this.router = _router; 

  if(_params.params.id != null){

      //This is where I get the error - when trying to get the id
      var email = _params.params.id;
  }
}
```

I actually get the param id fine.

The typescript compiler just doesn't like the type of var.

**Error Screen shot:**

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Could you give us the exact error? Thanks!

Comment: which version of tsc do you use?

Comment: This version: https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js

Comment: I installed it using npm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a try and it works for me without any error. Here is what I tried:

```
export class DetailsComponent {
  constructor(service:CompanyService, routeParams: RouteParams) {
    this.service = service;
    this.routeParams = routeParams;
    var idMethod1 = this.routeParams.params.id;
    var idMethod2 = this.routeParams.get('id'));
    (...)
  }
}
```

and I have this configuration for the route:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: ListComponent, name: 'Home', useAsDefault: true }
  { path: '/:id/:f', component: DetailsComponent, name: 'Details'}
])
export class AppComponent {
  (...)
}
```

Here is the version of my TypeScript compiler:

```
$ tsc -v
message TS6029: Version 1.7.5
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks.

I used _params.get('id'); and it seemed to fix the typescript compiler error.

Comment: Ah okay. I saw `_params.params.id` in the code you provided in your question ;-) BTW pleased to hear that you fixed your problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There's no such property `id` on the [`RouteParams`](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/RouteParams-class.html) class. You would rather use the `get` method:

```
var email = _params.get('id');
```

or if you prefer the `params` dictionary:

```
var email = _params.params['id'];
```

By the way you can try using [`Visual Studio Code`](https://code.visualstudio.com/). It has pretty decent Intellisense which helps in those situations.